# How do I properly create a text field with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, createjs

In my code below I'm trying to create a text field on the stage of the pong game. I cant seem to get it to show up on the stage. The code in question is in the main function.

First attempt at jquery and javascript here.

Thanks for your help.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pong</title>

    <!-- Basic styling, centering the canvas -->
    <style>
    canvas {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.createjs.com/createjs-2013.12.12.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script>

    var
    /**
     * Constants
     */
     score=0,
    WIDTH = 700,
    HEIGHT = 600,
    pi = Math.PI,
    UpArrow = 38,
    DownArrow = 40,
    /**
     * Game elements
     */
    canvas,
    ctx,
    keystate,
    /**
     * The player paddle
     * 
     * @type {Object}
     */
    player = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        width: 20,
        height: 100,
        /**
         * Update the position depending on pressed keys
         */
        update: function () {
            if (keystate[UpArrow]) this.y -= 7;
            if (keystate[DownArrow]) this.y += 7;
            // keep the paddle inside of the canvas
            this.y = Math.max(Math.min(this.y, HEIGHT - this.height), 0);
        },
        /**
         * Draw the player paddle to the canvas
         */
        draw: function () {
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    },
    /**
     * The ai paddle
     * 
     * @type {Object}
     */
    ai = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        width: 20,
        height: 100,
        /**
         * Update the position depending on the ball position
         */
        update: function () {
            // calculate ideal position
            var desty = ball.y - (this.height - ball.side) * 0.5;
            // ease the movement towards the ideal position
            this.y += (desty - this.y) * 0.1;
            // keep the paddle inside of the canvas
            this.y = Math.max(Math.min(this.y, HEIGHT - this.height), 0);
        },
        /**
         * Draw the ai paddle to the canvas
         */
        draw: function () {
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    },
    /** 
     * The ball object
     * 
     * @type {Object}
     */
    ball = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        vel: null,
        side: 20,
        speed: 12,
        /**
         * Serves the ball towards the specified side
         * 
         * @param  {number} side 1 right
         *                       -1 left
         */
        serve: function (side) {
            // set the x and y position
            var r = Math.random();
            this.x = side === 1 ? player.x + player.width : ai.x - this.side;
            this.y = (HEIGHT - this.side) * r;
            // calculate out-angle, higher/lower on the y-axis =>
            // steeper angle
            var phi = 0.1 * pi * (1 - 2 * r);
            // set velocity direction and magnitude
            this.vel = {
                x: side * this.speed * Math.cos(phi),
                y: this.speed * Math.sin(phi)
            }
        },
        /**
         * Update the ball position and keep it within the canvas
         */
        update: function () {
            // update position with current velocity
            this.x += this.vel.x;
            this.y += this.vel.y;
            // check if out of the canvas in the y direction
            if (0 > this.y || this.y + this.side > HEIGHT) {

                // calculate and add the right offset, i.e. how far
                // inside of the canvas the ball is
                var offset = this.vel.y < 0 ? 0 - this.y : HEIGHT - (this.y + this.side);
                this.y += 2 * offset;
                // mirror the y velocity
                this.vel.y *= -1;
            }
            // helper function to check intesectiont between two
            // axis aligned bounding boxex (AABB)
            var AABBIntersect = function (ax, ay, aw, ah, bx, by, bw, bh) {
                return ax < bx + bw && ay < by + bh && bx < ax + aw && by < ay + ah;
            };
            // check againts target paddle to check collision in x
            // direction
            var pdle = this.vel.x < 0 ? player : ai;
            if (AABBIntersect(pdle.x, pdle.y, pdle.width, pdle.height,
                    this.x, this.y, this.side, this.side)
            ) {
                // set the x position and calculate reflection angle
                this.x = pdle === player ? player.x + player.width : ai.x - this.side;
                var n = (this.y + this.side - pdle.y) / (pdle.height + this.side);
                var phi = 0.25 * pi * (2 * n - 1); // pi/4 = 45
                // calculate smash value and update velocity
                var smash = Math.abs(phi) > 0.2 * pi ? 1.5 : 1;
                this.vel.x = smash * (pdle === player ? 1 : -1) * this.speed * Math.cos(phi);
                this.vel.y = smash * this.speed * Math.sin(phi);
            }
            // reset the ball when ball outside of the canvas in the
            // x direction
            if (0 > this.x + this.side || this.x > WIDTH) {
                this.serve(pdle === player ? 1 : -1);

            }
        },
        /**
         * Draw the ball to the canvas
         */
        draw: function () {
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.side, this.side);
        }
    };
    /**
     * Starts the game
     */
    function main() {
        // create, initiate and append game canvas
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = WIDTH;
        canvas.height = HEIGHT;
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        keystate = {};
        // keep track of keyboard presses
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
            keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
        });
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
            delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
        });

        init(); // initiate game objects
        // game loop function
        var loop = function () {
            update();
            draw();
            window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
        };
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);

 //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 //Start of code that needs some help
 //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        var instructions = new createjs.Container();
        instructions.alpha = 0;
        instructions.regX = 125;
        instructions.regY = 70;

        instructions.x = stage.canvas.width / 2;
        instructions.y = stage.canvas.height / 2;

        var displayBox = new createjs.Shape();
        displayBox.graphics.beginFill("white").beginStroke("#000").setStrokeStyle(1).drawRoundRect(0, 0, instructions.regX * 2, instructions.regY * 2, 5).endFill().endStroke();


        var text = new createjs.Text("Here are the instructions.  Click to continue, or else!!", "15pt Arial", "red");
        text.lineWidth = 250;
        text.textAlign = "center";
        text.x = instructions.regX;
        text.y = 10;

        //instructions.addEventListener("click", handleInstructionsClick);

        instructions.addChild(displayBox, text);


        stage.addChild(instructions);
       // createjs.Tween.get(instructions).to({ alpha: 1 }, 500);

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//End of bad code block
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    }
    /**
     * Initatite game objects and set start positions
     */
    function init() {
        player.x = player.width;
        player.y = (HEIGHT - player.height) / 2;
        ai.x = WIDTH - (player.width + ai.width);
        ai.y = (HEIGHT - ai.height) / 2;
        ball.serve(1);


    }
    /**
     * Update all game objects
     */
    function update() {
        ball.update();
        player.update();
        ai.update();
    }
    /**
     * Clear canvas and draw all game objects and net
     */
    function draw() {
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        ball.draw();
        player.draw();
        ai.draw();
        // draw the net
        var w = 4;
        var x = (WIDTH - w) * 0.5;
        var y = 0;
        var step = HEIGHT / 20; // how many net segments
        while (y < HEIGHT) {
            ctx.fillRect(x, y + step * 0.25, w, step * 0.5);
            y += step;
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }
    // start and run the game
    main();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you can add any element like text field (`<input>`) in your page. It's hidden because the `<canvas>` is above it and covers it.

To add element:

```
textField = document.createElement("input");
textField.type = "text";
document.body.appendChild(textField);
```

To make it visible:

```
input{position: relative;}
```

Here's the final demo:

```js
var
/**
 * Constants
 */
score = 0,
    WIDTH = 700,
    HEIGHT = 600,
    pi = Math.PI,
    UpArrow = 38,
    DownArrow = 40,
    /**
     * Game elements
     */
    canvas,
    ctx,
    keystate,
    /**
     * The player paddle
     * 
     * @type {Object}
     */
    player = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        width: 20,
        height: 100,
        /**
         * Update the position depending on pressed keys
         */
        update: function () {
            if (keystate[UpArrow]) this.y -= 7;
            if (keystate[DownArrow]) this.y += 7;
            // keep the paddle inside of the canvas
            this.y = Math.max(Math.min(this.y, HEIGHT - this.height), 0);
        },
        /**
         * Draw the player paddle to the canvas
         */
        draw: function () {
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    },
    /**
     * The ai paddle
     * 
     * @type {Object}
     */
    ai = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        width: 20,
        height: 100,
        /**
         * Update the position depending on the ball position
         */
        update: function () {
            // calculate ideal position
            var desty = ball.y - (this.height - ball.side) * 0.5;
            // ease the movement towards the ideal position
            this.y += (desty - this.y) * 0.1;
            // keep the paddle inside of the canvas
            this.y = Math.max(Math.min(this.y, HEIGHT - this.height), 0);
        },
        /**
         * Draw the ai paddle to the canvas
         */
        draw: function () {
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    },
    /** 
     * The ball object
     * 
     * @type {Object}
     */
    ball = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        vel: null,
        side: 20,
        speed: 12,
        /**
         * Serves the ball towards the specified side
         * 
         * @param  {number} side 1 right
         *                       -1 left
         */
        serve: function (side) {
            // set the x and y position
            var r = Math.random();
            this.x = side === 1 ? player.x + player.width : ai.x - this.side;
            this.y = (HEIGHT - this.side) * r;
            // calculate out-angle, higher/lower on the y-axis =>
            // steeper angle
            var phi = 0.1 * pi * (1 - 2 * r);
            // set velocity direction and magnitude
            this.vel = {
                x: side * this.speed * Math.cos(phi),
                y: this.speed * Math.sin(phi)
            }
        },
        /**
         * Update the ball position and keep it within the canvas
         */
        update: function () {
            // update position with current velocity
            this.x += this.vel.x;
            this.y += this.vel.y;
            // check if out of the canvas in the y direction
            if (0 > this.y || this.y + this.side > HEIGHT) {

                // calculate and add the right offset, i.e. how far
                // inside of the canvas the ball is
                var offset = this.vel.y < 0 ? 0 - this.y : HEIGHT - (this.y + this.side);
                this.y += 2 * offset;
                // mirror the y velocity
                this.vel.y *= -1;
            }
            // helper function to check intesectiont between two
            // axis aligned bounding boxex (AABB)
            var AABBIntersect = function (ax, ay, aw, ah, bx, by, bw, bh) {
                return ax < bx + bw && ay < by + bh && bx < ax + aw && by < ay + ah;
            };
            // check againts target paddle to check collision in x
            // direction
            var pdle = this.vel.x < 0 ? player : ai;
            if (AABBIntersect(pdle.x, pdle.y, pdle.width, pdle.height,
            this.x, this.y, this.side, this.side)) {
                // set the x position and calculate reflection angle
                this.x = pdle === player ? player.x + player.width : ai.x - this.side;
                var n = (this.y + this.side - pdle.y) / (pdle.height + this.side);
                var phi = 0.25 * pi * (2 * n - 1); // pi/4 = 45
                // calculate smash value and update velocity
                var smash = Math.abs(phi) > 0.2 * pi ? 1.5 : 1;
                this.vel.x = smash * (pdle === player ? 1 : -1) * this.speed * Math.cos(phi);
                this.vel.y = smash * this.speed * Math.sin(phi);
            }
            // reset the ball when ball outside of the canvas in the
            // x direction
            if (0 > this.x + this.side || this.x > WIDTH) {
                this.serve(pdle === player ? 1 : -1);

            }
        },
        /**
         * Draw the ball to the canvas
         */
        draw: function () {
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.side, this.side);
        }
    };
/**
 * Starts the game
 */
function main() {
    // create, initiate and append game canvas
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = WIDTH;
    canvas.height = HEIGHT;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    
    textField = document.createElement("input");
    textField.type = "text";
    document.body.appendChild(textField);
    
    keystate = {};
    // keep track of keyboard presses
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
        keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
    });
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
        delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
    });

    init(); // initiate game objects
    // game loop function
    var loop = function () {
        update();
        draw();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);

    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    //Start of code that needs some help
    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    var instructions = new createjs.Container();
    instructions.alpha = 0;
    instructions.regX = 125;
    instructions.regY = 70;

    instructions.x = stage.canvas.width / 2;
    instructions.y = stage.canvas.height / 2;

    var displayBox = new createjs.Shape();
    displayBox.graphics.beginFill("white").beginStroke("#000").setStrokeStyle(1).drawRoundRect(0, 0, instructions.regX * 2, instructions.regY * 2, 5).endFill().endStroke();


    var text = new createjs.Text("Here are the instructions.  Click to continue, or else!!", "15pt Arial", "red");
    text.lineWidth = 250;
    text.textAlign = "center";
    text.x = instructions.regX;
    text.y = 10;

    //instructions.addEventListener("click", handleInstructionsClick);

    instructions.addChild(displayBox, text);


    stage.addChild(instructions);
    // createjs.Tween.get(instructions).to({ alpha: 1 }, 500);

    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    //End of bad code block
    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

}
/**
 * Initatite game objects and set start positions
 */
function init() {
    player.x = player.width;
    player.y = (HEIGHT - player.height) / 2;
    ai.x = WIDTH - (player.width + ai.width);
    ai.y = (HEIGHT - ai.height) / 2;
    ball.serve(1);


}
/**
 * Update all game objects
 */
function update() {
    ball.update();
    player.update();
    ai.update();
}
/**
 * Clear canvas and draw all game objects and net
 */
function draw() {
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ball.draw();
    player.draw();
    ai.draw();
    // draw the net
    var w = 4;
    var x = (WIDTH - w) * 0.5;
    var y = 0;
    var step = HEIGHT / 20; // how many net segments
    while (y < HEIGHT) {
        ctx.fillRect(x, y + step * 0.25, w, step * 0.5);
        y += step;
    }
    ctx.restore();
}
// start and run the game
main();
```

```css
canvas {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

input{position: relative;}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/createjs-2013.12.12.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery, try this

```
$("body").append('<input type="text" name="myTextName" id="myTextId" class="myTextClass"/>');
```